# Spring-Boot Hibernate - Query a table of which the name changes daily

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, entity, dto

I have a table of which the name format is **A|datecode|_AJOB**. Overnight a new table is created with the name **A|today_datecode|_AJOB** and data flow is directed to the new table. There is a process called new date process and it inputs a table named **COMM** which has just one data raw with all the information regarding the currently active date. This table has a field of active  **|today_datecode|** so that I can find which **AJOB** table is active at the moment.
I'm writing a Spring Boot Hibernate application to extract data from this table.

What's the best way to declare my **AJOB** Entity class? I'm not sure how to declare **@Table** annotation as the table name is dynamic.

What are my options?

If someone can provide me with an example that would be great

My Environment:
Spring Boot 2.2.4
Java 8
Hibernate
SQLServer DB